# One year old Seagate Barracuda hard disk in laptop sporadically unmount or freezes without warning

Tags: hard-drive, freeze

I bought a new Seagate Barracuda [ST1000LM048](https://www.seagate.com/www-content/product-content/barracuda-fam/barracuda-new/files/barracuda-2-5-final-ds1907-1-1609gb.pdf) hard disk 1 year ago for my laptop running Windows 10 Pro 64bit and using it as a secondry storage. Mounted the hard disk with a [CD-Rom adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004FM4UGE). The hard disk was working fine until last week.

- When I try to read/write any data to hard disk, file explorer or any program which uses the files in that drive, freezes. During the freeze, hard disk disconnects and cannot be seen from "This PC" or Disk Management. Disk comes back after few minutes and read/write process continues fine.
- Somehow, the disk is working fine after a reboot. But this issue happens more frequent when the PC is on for a longer time.
- Tried defragmentation and disk-clean up, but no hope.
- Checked for bad sectors, no problems what so ever.
- I am not very sure but it can be related; I first encountered this issue when I was trying to unzip a 2GB folder which contains around 1800 files. While I was unzipping the folder WinRar stuck, waited round 1-2 hours with no progress and finally decided to close it over task manager. And hard disk disconnected, after a reboot I was able to see the drive again.

I have no idea if this is a hardware or OS releated but before I give it to the service (guarantee), I would like to know if I can try anything or learn what's going on.

**Edit**

GSmartControl detailed log output can be seen [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wtIIwj2rgj8NMFex-mEEmwPpdQOq_VMN).

- No attributes failed.
- Short Self-test: Completed without error - 3637 lifetime hours
- Conveyance Self-test: Completed without error - 3637 lifetime hours
- Error Log

  - Error #3 - 3631 hours - active or idle - Uncorrectable error in data
  - Error #2 - 2854 hours - active or idle - Uncorrectable error in data
  - Error #1 - 2544 hours - active or idle - Uncorrectable error in data

Comment: Download [GSmartControl](https://gsmartcontrol.sourceforge.io/home/index.php/Downloads) and check [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) attributes, if there would be any light or dark red rows then HDD is failing

Comment: Thank you for your corrections.
I will return with additional information after I check it.

Comment: According to SMART, hdd is in a good shape, I wouldn't blame adapter since it looks as a passive connector that hooks to SATA port directly in place of CDROM. Try to run SMART long test, it will check physical surface of plates.

Comment: Sure. I will post as soon as the test ends.

Comment: Make sure the drive is not the only copy of anything important.  Also, don't rely on it for backup of anything important.  My experience is that once any physical issues show up, the drive is no longer trustworthy.